# Is it allowed to have several bluetooth devices with the same MAC address?

Tags: bluetooth

I am currently working with Bluetooth, and I am wondering if it is allowed (legally speaking) to have, in the field, several bluetooth devices with the MAC address?

Background: These bluetooth dongles will never be in discovery mode, and will only be used to check if a smartphone is in the neighbourhood. Having the same MAC address for all these bluetooth dongles would be helpful to avoid performing the pairing between the smartphone and each dongle.

Thanks.

Comment: Why would the government have enacted a law specifying the hardware address requirements on a particular protocol for wireless computer communication? And if that's what you are really after, you'll at least have to specify where you are located, since laws vary by locale.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unique MAC addresses are a voluntary industry standard, not any kind of legal proscription.  Duplicate MAC can lead to all sorts of hard-to-debug network errors though, so be sure not to allow duplicates on one network.

As [Michael Kjörling](https://superuser.com/users/53590/michael-kjorling) said [in the commments](https://superuser.com/questions/628108/is-it-allowed-to-have-several-bluetooth-devices-with-the-same-mac-address#comment782564_628108), laws vary by jurisdiction.  Consult a lawyer if you need real legal advice.  It's possible your local authorities might have implemented some kind of law related to MAC address, or might in the future.  I've never heard of one, but governments enact some pretty stupid laws from time to time, and "unique identifiers" of any kind tend to be attractive to some.